# Redirecting to http address with webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, redirect

So i have a case where i have a webservice that should take a caller and from the call do different stuff and then redirect the caller to a specific address.

```
public Response myWebservice(jsonObject json)
{
    {
          //Do other stuff
    }
          //Redirect to http://www.myaddress.com/myaddress
}
```

So far i have tried to play around with some HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("address"); but it hasnt really brought me anywhere so i thought i would ask here for some guidance that might get me a bit further down the road.

Comment: Response.Redirect("http ://www.microsoft.com/gohere/look.htm"); Are you specifying shema as well?? http

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
public Response myWebservice(jsonObject json)
{
    {
          //Do other stuff
    }
    //Redirect to http://www.myaddress.com/myaddress
    Context.Response.StatusCode = 307;
    Context.Response.AddHeader("Location","http://www.myaddress.com/myaddress");
    return null;
}
```

Found code [here](http://books.google.lt/books?id=Rp7oNYz4G6UC&pg=PA46&dq=redirect+request+in+web+service&hl=lt&sa=X&ei=l-dQVIvCJaX6ygOVuICoAQ&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=redirect%20request%20in%20web%20service&f=false) and [here](http://community.sitepoint.com/t/reponse-redirect-in-a-web-service/1993/3)